# Trying to replace a substring of a string with another substring

Tags: java

I'm trying to take this string

```
where lowercase(pdd.last_name) like 'albert%'
```

and replace "pdd" with "p" using this function

```
sb.replace(queryAdd.indexOf("pdd"), (queryAdd.indexOf("pdd") + 3), "p");
```

where sb is a StringBuffer, but it doesn't work and here's what it actually returns

```
where lowercase(pdpast_name) like 'albert%'
```

Why does this not replace "pdd" with "p"?

Comment: Yes i have. re-read the question please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer("where lowercase(pdd.last_name) like 'albert%'");
    s.replace(s.indexOf("pdd"),(s.indexOf("pdd")+3), "p");
    System.out.println(s);
```

I think your sb and queryAdd have different data.

Comment: Oh god i think you're right. I shouldn't have been using my queryAdd var for the index, but my string buffer as you've suggested. I've been trying to get this to work for wayyy too long. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String str = "where lowercase(pdd.last_name) like 'albert%'";
str = str.replaceFirst("pdd", "p");
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked in my case. Have a look at my code (I am assuming this is what you are trying to do)....

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("where lowercase(pdd.last_name) like 'albert%'");
        String queryAdd="where lowercase(pdd.last_name) like 'albert%'";
        sb.replace(queryAdd.indexOf("pdd"), (queryAdd.indexOf("pdd") + 3), "p");
        System.out.println(sb);
```

Output:  `where lowercase(p.last_name) like 'albert%'`